# Close opened activity, so main activity can update fragment without state loss in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity

I currently have two activities, the first one which is called when the app is opened, `EventsActivity` , and the second one which comes from `EventsActivity` called `EventActivity`.   If `EventActivity` is opened during a notification, which I process through `EventsActivity` within an onIntent, there is a `state loss` error because `EventActivity` is open.   How can I close `EventActivity` before updating my fragment in `EventsActivity`.

**Launch EventActivity from EventsActivity**

```
public void launchEvent() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, EventActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

**Update View Based On Notification From EventsActivity (EventActivity Is Opened)**

```
@Override
    public void onNewIntent (Intent intent)
    {
FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = manager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, new MessageFragment());
        manager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE); // <!-- state loss exception
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `super.onNewIntent(intent)` to tell the FragmentManager that it is safe to do Fragment transactions.

```
@Override
public void onNewIntent (Intent intent)
{
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = manager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, new MessageFragment());
    manager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```